# Slow Scene rendering at first open

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

My scene is rendered slowly at first open. From second times it is almost rendered immediately. I tried to remove all textures but no efect. The script is still invoked but texture is rendered after 10 seconds. I just meet this problem on iOS.
I stuck for few days and i really need suggestion from everyone. I'm using Unity 5.0.1.

Comment: Please dont use the "unity" tag for questions related to the game engine, just use "unity3d" instead.

Comment: Perhaps it'd help to describe the scene and/or post the code you suspect is slowing things down. Otherwise any help will likely just be speculation.

Comment: Maybye some scripts are still compiling. Do you see spinning icon?

Comment: @MichaelTang i tried to find issues in code but not found. The code in start method of each script run very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Use Unity Profiler to debug the issue.

Comment: I tried many times. It showed me two values which are cause of my problem: Cpu player and Timeframe. The max value of those index is larger than 5 seconds. That is exactly time i have to wait the scene display on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable "Deep Profile" in the Profiler. This will provide you a more detailed overview of your time consuming actions of your application. Search for the node which consumes the highest amount of milliseconds needed for performing an operation. Extend this node and traverse the tree until you find the invoked method causing your problem.